# Using the HedgehogDevelopment.TDS NuGet package causes build error in TeamCity

Tags: tds

I am setting up the Hedgehog.TDS nuget package as per https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/TDS-Classic-License-NuGet-Package

I am using this on TeamCity and we still have agents that have TDS installed

I was hoping that I could use the Nuget package setup alongside other projects that still required TDS to be installed while we migrate. However I am getting the following error on the build server:

```
 E:\Work\23fd9662408071fa\src\Demo\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.6.0.13\build\
 HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets(362,109): error MSB4064: The "ConfigurationToBuild" parameter is not supported by the "GetProjectContentFiles" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, 
 and it is a settable public instance property. [E:\Work\23fd9662408071fa\src\Demo
 \Demo.Components.TDS.Master\Demo.Components.TDS.Master.scproj]


 E:\Work\23fd9662408071fa\src\Demo\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.6.0.13\build\
 HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets(362,5): error MSB4063: The "GetProjectContentFiles" task 
 could not be initialized with its input parameters.  [E:\Work\23fd9662408071fa\src\Demo\
 Demo.Components.TDS.Master\Demo.Components.TDS.Master.scproj]
```

What is causing this error? Is it because the Nuget and MSBuild target files or DLLs compete with each other?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved ? if so could you please share the root cause and how fixed this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and in my case, I had multiple import lines (one from old installed TDS and one from the NuGet package). I had to manually remove the installed TDS import line from the project file.

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets')"/>`

`<Import Project="..\..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.14\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.14\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets')" />`

An error was resolved after removing the first import line.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is open up your .scproj file in a text editor, and make sure that at the bottom it only references the HedgeHogDevelopment Nuget Package Folder. Anything that references to your c:\program files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\ should not be there.

This is what mine looks like

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.7.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.7.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.7.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.7.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets')" />
```